# Redirect website from http to https

Tags: c#, iis, azure

I have a website stored on azure for which I got an SSL certificate. I am trying to redirect www.mywebsite.com to https://www.mywebsite.com but with no success.

I am using the following code that should change the configuration of IIS where my project is deployed :

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But when I type my URL it does not redirect to https.

By the way, rewrite appears unrecorgnized by Intellisense.

Comment: Related - make sure you read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365294/is-redirecting-http-to-https-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see that you've taken the code snipet from [Steve Marx example](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/redirecting-to-https-in-windows-azure-two-methods)

The problem is that you have whitespace in your rule name. Just remove them and it will work.

> The name attribute of rule must not have spaces; the rule won’t work correctly in IIS on Azure with spaces in the name.

Find the full article here:
[Azure https guide](http://ianobermiller.com/blog/2012/07/20/require-https-on-azure/)