# Check web page url and make https if entered as http

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that is routed with https and all works well.
I noticed I could change it to http and the page still loaded.

I am trying to check the window url and make it https if it was entered as http. Only for this page and with Jquery or Javascript. ( I know most would recommend not using a script for security )

This isn't working for me:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.pathname;
if url.match('^http://')
{
url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//, 'https://');
    window.location.pathname = url;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You should be doing this server-side.

Comment: That might not be working for you because you’re missing parentheses around the `if`’s condition. I’m pretty sure that’s at least one part of it. But yes, do it server-side.

Comment: Should be done using .htaccess. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www

Comment: `window.location.pathname` returns the path in the URL after the `.tld`. You want to use `window.location.protcol`. But even then, this type of operation is best done in .htaccess.

Comment: Would a CSRF or XSS be able to put this as a script and have it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect HTTP or HTTPS then force HTTPS in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript)

Comment: Related: [Is redirecting http to https a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365294/is-redirecting-http-to-https-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it client side:

```
<script>

   if (  window.location.protocol != 'https:' ) {
           window.location = document.URL.replace("http://","https://");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You should anchor your expression lest it replace `http://` anywhere in the URL, i.e. `/^http:\/\//`.

Comment: Exactly. Or use substring like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript